# Simple Ant build in STS can't find jdk1.7.0_11/lib/tools.jar

Tags: java, ant

I created a basic Ant build using [nice tutorial on Apache website](https://ant.apache.org/manual/tutorial-HelloWorldWithAnt.html).

```
<project>
    <target name="clean">
        <delete dir="bin"/>
    </target>

    <target name="compile">
        <mkdir dir="bin"/>
        <javac srcdir="jar" destdir="bin"/>
    </target>

    <target name="jar">
        <jar destfile="HelloWorld.jar" basedir="bin">
            <manifest>
            </manifest>
        </jar>
    </target>
</project>
```

This should match my folder structure:

[image: image description]

But I get an error:

```
The archive: C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Java/jdk1.7.0_11/lib/tools.jar which is referenced by the classpath, does not exist.
```

The file exists on that path, but of course you must replace URL encoded characters `%20%`->.

I'm not sure if the URL encoded spaces cause the error though. Could anyone tell me what's going on with Ant? I'd like to use Ant instead of my ad-hoc batch-file build system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the problem by setting environment variable `JAVA_HOME` to correct **JDK** (not JRE) path. This can be done in control panel or using utility programs.